# Fixing bevel corners

Tags: modeling, bevel

Is there an automated way to get rid of intersecting bevel corners visible on the attached screenshot? Thank you.

[image: Blender bevel corner]

Comment: Hello and welcome. There is no automated way. What you can do is select either one of the overlapping faces (not both sides) and press `ctrl+f` > *Intersect (Knife)* then manually delete the excess faces.

Comment: I've seen MESHmachine highly recommended as it can sometimes avoid this problem.
https://blendermarket.com/products/meshmachine